# timeout on ReadLine from StandardOutput stream of process vb.net 2012

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, process, streamreader

I have a process running. It should only take 1.5 minutes to run.. but sometimes something happens so at ReadLine it will get stuck. I am processing a video file.. I need a way to kill this process if it goes beyond the 3 min mark. I already have the condition handled if the process is killed.. I thought I could run a timer and after 3 minutes kill the process but ReadLine locks the thread.. this function is running in a thread on my main program..

Comment: Show us the code your using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a timer it should be done on a second thread. a Console.ReadLine() will lock up your single thread.

using `System.Threading.Timer`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used.. Thanks colton for pointing my the right direction

```
    Dim tmr As New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf MyTimerTick)
    tmr.Change(180000, 0)
```